# Почему некорректно работает пагинация при фильтрации?

Tags: php, jquery, filter, pagination

прошу совета и помощи.

У меня есть страница, на которой я вывожу информацию из БД.
И так как информации много, то нужно сделать пагинацию. Чтобы не писать велосипед нашел на хорошем сайте класс пагинации. [тут](https://snipp.ru/php/paginator-mysql)

И использую его. Появилась проблема:

При загрузке страницы все работает хорошо:

```
// пагинация
include($dr.'/pagination/pagination.php');
$peger = new DBPaginator($url2, 6);  // 6 - колво выводов на странице

$items = $peger->getItems("SELECT * FROM `apple` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

foreach ($items as $item){
...
}
```

Так пагинация работает отлично. НО.

У меня есть фильтры.

Допустим, на страницу из БД я вывожу все яблоки. Пагинатор на странице выводит по 6 яблок и снизу сама навигация

**1,2,3,4,5....**

Если я выбираю фильтр (например, красные яблоки), в это время Ajax отправляет запрос в php с указанным значением фильтра (**red**, например). Php принимает значение фильтра и делает новую выборку из БД

```
// пагинация
include($dr.'/pagination/pagination.php');
$peger = new DBPaginator($urlForPagi, 6);  // 6 - колво выводов на странице

$items = $peger->getItems("SELECT * FROM `apple ` WHERE `color` = $_POST['color'] ORDER BY id DESC");
```

и через **echo json_encode** отдает результат, а **jquery** подгружает на страницу новые яблоки, удаляя предыдущие. Без перезагрузки страницы. А также подгружается новая пагинация (пагинация новой выборки (**красные яблоки**)).

Мне непонятно следующее. При выводе всех яблок на странице есть пагинация, например **1,2,3,4,5,** и когда выбрали красные яблоки, то старая пагинация удаляется и подгружается новая из выборки **1,2** (по 6 штук красных яблок на странице) - посчитал красные яблоки в БД и понял что пагинация работает в этом смысле правильно. НО.

Когда загрузились только красные яблоки из БД и появилась пагинация красных яблок, стоит нажать, например, на страницу 2, то почему-то выводятся все яблоки, а должны только красные.

Comment: пардоньте, конечно, но это лучше вам поискать другие "примеры", а не вот это вот.

Comment: выводятся все, потому что начальный фильтр вы берете из $_POST а когда кликаете в ссылку пагинации, то там уже никаких данных о фильтре не остается. Ссылка пагинации также должна хранить состояние фильтрации. В данном контексте, начальный фильтры надо убрать в `$_GET['color']`, и модифицировать ссылка пагинации чтобы они включали указанный параметр.

Comment: @teran может подскажите другие примеры?

Comment: при переходе на страницу вы говорите "хочу перейти на страницу 2", а нужно говорить "хочу перейти на страницу 2 с фильтром 'красное яблоко' ", дорисуйте js-ом в ссылку на кнопке пагинации недостающий query параметр, и будет вам счастье

Comment: @AlexKhonko какой еще костыль предложите этому и без того убогому коду приписать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пагинацию можно и без сторонних библиотек сделать:)

Краткий пример из моих проектов:)

```
$_COUNT = 15; // Кол-во выводим элементов на странице
$_GET['page'] = (int)$_GET['page']; // Текущая страницы

if ($_GET['page']) $_GET['page'] -= 1; // В БД нумерация для LIMIT начинается с 0, а для клиента с 1, поэтому вычитаем -1 для выборки

$_LIMIT = ($_GET['page'] * $_COUNT).",".$_COUNT;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_LIMIT;
```

Comment: А можете дать краткий пример как из Вашего первого примера составить сам пагинатор? (нумерацию страниц с ссылками), пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот функция из старого проекта, если не получится под себя переделать, сегодня вечером напишу более современный код:
https://pastebin.com/XwQ8HPdm

Comment: Был бы Вам премного благодарен

Comment: Сможете помочь?

Comment: @MichaelMiller Извиняюсь что долго, но постарался расписать более понятные комментарии к коду:
https://pastebin.com/ZuXQ9V5B

Comment: @MichaelMiller Написал простуб либу, где учел все возможные нюансы, вот репозиторий https://github.com/DeveloperVusal/ConstructPagination

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше терпение, но оказывается я тупой в этом плане. Никак не получается использовать Ваш класс. Пытался написать еще функцию в классе getItems($sql), в которую буду аргументом передавать sql запрос и тут же считать кол-во строк в таблице и полученное кол-во сделать свойством переменной $count. Но как-то слишком сложно для меня дается пагинация. У Вас нет такого готового примера, извините за наглость?

Comment: @MichaelMiller Понимаю:)
Скиньте Ваш код например в pastebin, я посмотрю ибо не понял, где Вы зависли:)

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо еще раз за Ваш настрой помочь, я тоже иногда помогаю людям тем, что умею делать сам. Вот ссылка на pastebin ( только я почистил немного свой код чтобы объем был меньше для лучшего восприятия) https://pastebin.com/vhTQF9dR

Comment: Вы вообще хороший человек. Получилось подумать над Вашим кодом и немного подделать под себя. Спасибище Вам миллион раз(!)

Comment: @MichaelMiller Рад, что вы смогли решить свою задачу (проблему) :)

Comment: Спасибо. С пагинацией плюс минус смог разобраться как она делается, но осталась проблема с фильтрами, то есть когда подгружаю только красные яблоки, и если нажать на в плагиаторе на вторую страницу отфильтрованных красных яблок, то все равно выводятся все яблоки из БД. С этим еще предстоит разобраться.